# How can I check all historic values in a ReplaySubject in RxSwift?

Tags: rx-swift

I have a simple struct `Foo`:

```swift
struct Foo {
    let bar: String
}
```

Now I create an unbounded `ReplaySubject` of `Foo`s:

```swift
let subject = ReplaySubject<Foo>.createUnbounded()
```

How can I now understand whether the (unterminated) stream has a `Foo` whose `bar` was equal to `abc`? (This could be the 1st, 3rd, or 20th element.)

Comment: It sounds like you just need an Array

Comment: I kind of do, but since I'm in Rx world now I was wondering if it was possible to do without sort of duplicating that history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this is kind of a crazy request. You should not be thinking about "what was" when working with Rx. Rather you should be thinking about what is always the case. You should be thinking about invariants...

That said, the operator below will emit the indexes for you. Since the subject is able to constantly emit events, the operator is designed to work in real time. It can be used like this:

```
let indexes = subject.indexOfElementSatisfying { $0.bar == "abc" }
```

Here it is:

```
extension ObservableConvertibleType {

    /**
     Emits the index of all the values in the stream that satisfy the predicate.

     - parameter pred: The predicate that determines whether the value satisfies the condition
     - returns: An observable sequence of indexes to those elements.
     */
    func indexOfElementSatisfying(_ pred: @escaping (E) throws -> Bool) -> Observable<Int> {
        return asObservable()
            .enumerated()
            .filter { try pred($0.element) }
            .map { $0.index }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! Since you mentioned this is something I shouldn't do, am I thinking about this the wrong way? I tried to keep it as high-level as possible to convey my actual use case, which is "the user can perform any number of actions where `bar` ends up being set, how can I know if that was every set to `abc`". Should I just not use Rx for this situation then?

Comment: First you should phrase the use-case in the form of "(Some portion of) the app outputs X, every time the user does/inputs Y (under conditions Z)" Rx is output centric. Once you have a use-case along those lines, you can create an Observable chain that implements the use-case.

Comment: For example a use-case like, "Button Foo is enabled whenever the `bar` value of the latest `foo` object is set to "abc".

Comment: Interesting. I understand how to change my thinking and why that helps, just have to play some mental gymnastics to make this particular case fit. I'll toy around with it, appreciate the help!